# GSA: Exclude multiple files using as_filetype

Tags: google-search-appliance

I need to exclude multiple file types(`ppt,pdf,doc`) from my results
I have prepared URL parameter

```
&as_filetype=pdf,ppt$&as_ft=e
```

This is not working. Also if I want to exclude files like ppt, pptx, pptm is `ppt$` correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you do this at the collection level.

Log into your Search Appliance, go to Index and then Collections. Click on the Edit link next to the Collection you wish to exclude these files from.

In the box titled "Do Not Include Content Matching the Following Patterns" add the following:

```
.ppt$
.pdf$
.doc$
```

These regex patterns that will tell the GSA to exclude and documents ending with .ppt, .pdf and .doc. You can add other file types as you see fit.

HTH